# Applying Fourier transform to heat equation with source

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform

I haven't had any experience with applying of FT to heat equation with source. But this popped up in an exercise.

Any help in the **right direction** would be great.

Consider:

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial ^2u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} + Q(x,t)
$$ subject to 
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
x lies on the infinite domain.

Comment: have you tried taking the Fourier transform of each side?

Comment: I have. 
We have $$\bar{U}(\omega ,t)_{t} = -k \omega^{2} \bar{U}(\omega ,t) +\bar{Q}(\omega, t)$$

Comment: looks like a first order ODE to me :) (although  in FTs $x\to k$, not $\omega$

Comment: @danimal Not wanting to waste a huge amount of time on the wrong path, I used Mathematica to seek the general solution. Indeed the solution isn't pretty. So I was wondering if I'm applying the right technique

Comment: If you use mathematica for a general solution, you usually won't get pretty results! try the time FT instead of the space one

Comment: @danimal Let me see how far I can go

Comment: @danimal while performing the integrating factor, I had problems integrating the source Q. Am I supposed to use the table of Fourier transform? The issue is I do not have a negative i on the side of Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reduces to a first order ODE in time
$$
              \frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}(s,t)=-ks^{2}\hat{u}(s,t)+\hat{Q}(s,t) \\
              \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{ks^{2}t}\hat{u}(s,t)\right)=e^{ks^{2}t}\hat{Q}(s,t) \\
          e^{ks^{2}t}\hat{u}(s,t)-\hat{u}(s,0) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{ks^{2}t'}\hat{Q}(s,t')dt' \\
        \hat{u}(s,t)=e^{-ks^{2}t}\hat{f}(s)+\int_{0}^{t}e^{-ks^{2}(t-t')}\hat{Q}(s,t')dt'
$$
Now inverse transform:
$$
    u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)e^{-ks^{2}t}e^{isx}ds+\int_{0}^{t}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{Q}(s,t')e^{-ks^{2}(t-t')}dsdt'
$$
Then use the symmetry identity
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{a}(s)b(s)ds = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a(x)\hat{b}(x)dx
$$
along with the Fourier transform identity,
$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-kts^{2}}e^{isx}ds=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}e^{-tx^{2}/4kt}.
$$
The final answer should be--assuming no typos--the following
\begin{align}
     u(x,t) & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
     e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4kt}f(y)dy \\ & +\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k(t-t')}}
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4k(t-t')}Q(y,t')dy dt'
\end{align}
In terms of the ordinary time propogater $T(t)$,
$$
           u(x,t) = T(t)f + \int_{0}^{t}T(t-t')Q(x,t')dt'
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
But if I may trouble you, why do you subtract the initial condition on the third line of the reasoning?

Comment: @Mathematicing : I actually integrated $\frac{d}{dt'}(\cdot)$ in $t'$ over $[0,t]$, which gave the difference of two evaluation terms.

Comment: I'm still confused. I could be right to say that u(s,0) came from the right hand side and I think it's the evaluation of the integral symbolically that is causing confusion.

Comment: It's from the left side $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{d}{dt'}\left(e^{ks^{2}t'}\hat{u}(s,t')\right)dt'= e^{ks^{2}t}\hat{u}(s,t)-\hat{u}(s,0)$, @Mathematicing

Comment: I see why. You're awesome!